# SSRS 2019, summarizing calculated expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I'm using a matrix to show salespersons orders for each month of the year.
rows - state, salesperson name
columns - year, month
data - number of orders

for each salesperson I have the total number of orders per year.
based on that I have a calculation that shows if the salesperson met his target or not.

```
=IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value)>=50, "met target", "below target").
```

I need to add a total in state level - how many salespersons met their target and how many didn't.
That is, to show something like:

**10 met target**

**5 below target**

in state group total.

How can I do that?

I'm attaching an example based on my report (I can't publish the report).

Report

[image]

What I need is highlighted in yellow. For state 04 I have 3 salespersons. 2 of them met their target and 1 didn't.

```
=SUM(IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value)>=50, 1, 0)) & " met target"
```

gives me 1 met target and not 2.

*edited April 1st 2020*

Alan, if I understand you correctly, I need to define on which scope to calculate the sum.

This part **sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value, "stateGroup")>=50** should be in the Salesperson level. so my scope is "Salesperson". The full expression is in the StateGroup total.

**=SUM(IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value, "Salesperson")>=50, 1, 0)) & " met target"**

But, when I try it, with either scope name, I get this error message:
*The value expression for the TextBox 'A' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate. The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate*.

So, what am I still doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add an example of how your table looks like?

Comment: You need to edit your original question rather than adding adding an answer.

Comment: I've edited this question, please remove the answer you added.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head but I think the following will work..

```
=SUM(IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value)>=50, 1, 0)) & " met target"
```

and

```
=SUM(IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value)<50, , 0)) & " below target"
```

**Update based on OP remarks**

If the expressions are in a different scope then you need to specify the scope.
e.g. If you States were grouped in a RowGroup called `stateGroup` then the expression would be something like.

```
=SUM(IIf(sum(Fields!OrderCount.Value, "stateGroup")>=50, 1, 0)) & " met target"
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark the answer as accepted. This helps other looking for answers to similar questions.

Comment: I get this error message: The value expression for the TextBox 'A' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate. The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.